# issue on Profiles export/import from magento1.4 to magento 1.6

Tags: magento

When trying to import the products from .csv file(which exported from 1.4 magento backend) into the magento1.6,I receive the errors like "Column names have duplicates".

Comment: What products.csv are you talking about? One you created yourself (programmatically), or one created by using the interactive export functionality of the Magento backend? No matter what, posting at least the header line (line 1) of the .csv file maybe helpful.

Comment: I have exported using the interactive export in magento backend

Answer (score 2):

Do your column names have duplicates?  The first row of a CSV is reserved for the field names of a product object (name, price, etc.).  Magento is telling you your CSV file is improperly formatted, as it's detected a column's been included twice.

There's two reasons this happens.  The first is: You actually have a duplicate column name.  Open your file in a spreadsheet program (Microsoft Excel, etc.) and make sure that none of your column names are repeated (including blank column names!)

The second reason is: The line endings of your text file

```
\n  (unix text files, sort-of Mac OS X text files)
\r  (unix text files, Mac OS < 10 text files, sometimes Mac OS X text files)
\r\n (windows text files)
```

are being misinterpreted by the server, and PHP thinks your entire text file is one line long.  Try saving your csv with different line endings (an option present in proper text editors)

Finally, Magento throw this exception here

```
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Adapter/Abstract.php
if (is_array($this->_colNames) && !empty($this->_colNames)) {
    $this->_colQuantity = count($this->_colNames);

    if (count(array_unique($this->_colNames)) != $this->_colQuantity) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Column names have duplicates'));
    }
} else {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Column names is empty or is not an array'));
}
```

Add some temporary debugging code and you'll be able to figure out why your particular installation is throwing this error.